# for the realization of an android application

Tags: android

I have a question about the realization of mobile application. Can you create an application that refers directly to the website?

Let me explain: can one create an application where the user clicks the icon of the app downloaded, it is sent to the application website, without opening the browser? Is this possible?

Comment: [Sure, it's possible. Next question.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: @MattBall: What about turning that into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [AppGeyser](http://www.appsgeyser.com/) which will make it really easy to do that. Other than that, you just need to embed a `WebView` and set the website in it. Have a look at products like Trigger.io.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, i watch now.